# How to create plugin for B4A

Tags: java, android, basic4android

i need to create activity for b4a,
so i have 2 questions:
1. is it possible to add java activity to b4a? its possible in unity, but is it possible here?
2. if not, how do i create a library for b4a ?

i tried find answer for that on the net, but nothing.

for example, on unity, if i create a class in java

```
public class AppayableUnityAdapter extends UnityPlayerActivity
```

and this class have

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

and i create a jar from it and add to the project and to the manifest, it just starts with the application. so is there a way to do that with B4A?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly what you are trying to do.

With the #Extends attribute you can extend the Activity from another base class. So for the UnityPlayerActivity you have to write something like:

```
#Extends: <packagename>.UnityPlayerActivity
```

Replace  with the correct package name of the UnityPlayerActivity class.